# Gatsbyjs - collapsing navbar with reactstrap

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, reactstrap

I'm working on a site I've build with Gatsby.js, and reactstrap for the ui components. But I have an problem with the collapsed navbar on smaller screens.

I need to collapse the navigation after each click to make it work with gatsby-link, but the collapse is not collapsed after a new page is loaded.

So I added a closeNavbar method to all links via onClick, but for whatever reasons this does not work.

Here is my navigation component:

```
import React from "react";
import Link from "gatsby-link";
import {
  Collapse,
  Container,
  Navbar,
  NavbarToggler,
  Nav,
  NavItem
} from "reactstrap";

export default class Navigation extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.toggleNavbar = this.toggleNavbar.bind(this);
    this.closeNavbar = this.closeNavbar.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      collapsed: true
    };
  }

  toggleNavbar() {
    this.setState({
      collapsed: !this.state.collapsed
    });
  }

  closeNavbar() {
    if (this.state.collapsed == true) {
      this.toggleNavbar();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <header>
        <Navbar className="navigation__navbar" light expand="md">
          <Container>
            <NavbarToggler onClick={this.toggleNavbar} className="mr-2" />
            <Collapse isOpen={!this.state.collapsed} navbar>
              <Nav className="mr-auto" navbar>
                <NavItem>
                  <Link className="nav-link navigation__navlinks" to="/">
                    Home
                  </Link>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem>
                  <Link
                    onClick={this.closeNavbar}
                    className="nav-link navigation__navlinks"
                    to="/leistungen/"
                  >
                    Leistungen
                  </Link>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem>
                  <Link
                    onClick={this.closeNavbar}
                    className="nav-link navigation__navlinks"
                    to="/kuechen/"
                  >
                    Küchen
                  </Link>
                </NavItem>
              </Nav>
            </Collapse>
          </Container>
        </Navbar>
      </header>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem, there is am issue on github : https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/issues/1157

Answer (score 0):

I had an error in the closeNavbar method. I tried to toggle it, only when it was already collapsed. This is the correct code:

```
  closeNavbar() {
    if (this.state.collapsed !== true) {
      this.toggleNavbar();
    }
  }
```